# scapy - how to display bit fields flags as on off?

Tags: scapy

scapy provides with FlagsField which show as

```
   flag1+flag2+flag5
```

Can this be printed as ?

```
   flag1=on
   flag2=on
   flag3=off
   flag4=off
   flag5=on
```

flagField take array-
but class can be a enum/dictionary which indexes a bit position.

Answer (score 0):

worked it

```
class CFlagsField(FlagsField):
    def i2repr(self, pkt, x):
        flgs = []
        for (k, v) in self.names.iteritems():
            tf = 'True' if x & (1<<k) else 'False'
            flgs.append('{:<20}={:^7}'.format(v, tf))
        return "\n".join(flgs)
```